# Adding Constraint Not To Superview, Can It Be Done?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have this case :

[image]

I want to put a button on top of UIImageView because I want to use the UIImageView as a container of few buttons. and I want to create a constraint for the button relates to UIImageView. for example, 10 pt from top of UIImageView. not to the superview. how to do that? because I see all options about constraint is always relates to superview.

[image]

UPDATE : here's what I have according to rdelmar's answer

[image]

as you can see in this picture, the 'facebook button' has constrain (vertical space) to navigation bar. not to the UIImageView.

UPDATE : here's what it looks like on my View Controller Scene

[image]

Comment: @robmayoff : I'm using Xcode 4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a constraint between your button and the image view, which is the button's superview, you should choose "Top Space To Superview". Since the superview of the button is the image view, not the controller's view, that should give you what you want. Once you've made that constraint, you should delete the one to the top of the controller's view.

Comment: this is not,he is looking for..he wants constraint with respect to imageview only

Comment: @rdelmar : glad to see you here again, professor... this time what I want to do is adding 20 pt space on top of the button relates to UIImageView. not the navigation bar or status bar.

Comment: @rdelmar: ok,but how can I have constraint for a button on imageview with respect to imageview instead of uiviewcontroller.

Comment: @RobertHanson, sorry, I was looking at your image incorrectly. I understand now. The button is a subview of the image view, right?

Comment: @rdelmar : yes, maybe you can check my update above to give you better illustration. thank you.

Comment: @rdelmar: yah..I was also thinking same.

Comment: @RobertHanson, I don't know how you made that constraint -- the choice "Top Space To Superview" should give you what you want, because the superview is the image view not the controller (assuming that the button is a subview of the image view).

Comment: @rdelmar : professor, if I have UIImageView then I put UIButton on top of it, just like my screenshot above, will Xcode automatically configure UIImageView as superview of UIButton? or should I manually add some code to make this hierarchy? thank you.

Comment: @RobertHanson, yes it should make it a subview. You can tell from the object list in IB -- the button should be listed under (and indented) the image view. Is it not?

Comment: @rdelmar : I just update my post. I agree with you about the position of those buttons should be listed under UIImageView. but as you can see there, all components listed under View. I tried to drag both buttons to be listed under Image View but can not move. how to make these buttons listed under Image View? thank you.

Comment: @RobertHanson, I don't know what to tell you. You should be able to drag the buttons (in the object list, not the canvas) up to right under the image view, and that should make it a subview. If not, then the only thing I can say is to delete those buttons and start over. If you drag the button into the image view, it should make it a subview of that image view.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode5 Control-click-and drag from the button to the image, a context menu will offer a number of possible constraints between the two objects. Not sure if that also works in Xcode4.